# Android MediaPlayer on UI Thread

Tags: android, media-player

When using android's mediaplayer to stream audio off the web, is it okay to call all the functions (stop(), reset(), setDataSource(), etc.) on the UI thread, or should I create a separate thread for that. In other words, will those functions ever take a few seconds to respond and thereby cause perceptible lag?

If I do have to call them from separate threads, what's the best way to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call MediaPlayer methods off the default app thread without any issues.  Do be sure to make proper use of its [state machine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), of course :)

Comment: What do you mean by "proper use of its state machine"?

Comment: The "state machine" words above are linked to the MediaPlayer class docs, and the state machine is diagrammed right at the top.  You have to call methods in the right order.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Didn't know what you meant

Comment: This is not true. We used to get lots of ANRs when running on the main UI thread. In particular this happens when calling reset() and perhaps others.